# Can a grounded thermocouple cause GFCI to trip?

Tags: thermocouple, gfci

I noticed the tip of my soldering iron is case grounded. I understand the GFCI compares voltages and trips if there is a difference (in the millivolt range). If the thermocouple generates a small amount of voltage, can't it trip the GCFI? Moreover, what does the GFCI use as a voltage reference?

Comment: It's not voltages that the GFCI/RCD is measuring, it's currents. It trips if there's a difference in the currents on the live and neutral wires.

Comment: Could you post a model number of your soldering iron, please?  I'm curious about its grounding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand the GFCI compares voltages and trips if there is a difference (in the millivolt range).

Actually, the GFCI compares *current* (in the "line" and "neutral" wires) and trips if there's a difference of more than a few mA.

> If the thermocouple generates a small amount of voltage, can't it trip the GCFI?

No, the thermocouple (if your iron even has one) would be unrelated to this.

> Moreover, what does the GFCI use as a voltage reference?

A GFCI does not need a great deal of precision, so it probably just uses a diode junction as a voltage reference.